# Docker port mapping not working

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

When I try to run two different versions of an app on different host port mappings I don't get a response from the docker container.

ex:

```
docker run --it -p 6443:443 --rm --privileged image1
docker run --it -p 7443:443 --rm --privileged image2
docker run -p 15672:15672 -d image3
```

UI for container from image3 comes up but no UI is available for containers from image1 and image2 depending upon which was run at the last.

Am I missing something here?

Access to UI - https://my_vm_ip:hostport

Please note that Security rules for this port are open to the world.

Answer (score 0):

`docker run --it -p --rm --privileged 6443:443 image1`

should be:

`docker run --it -p 6443:443 --rm --privileged image1`

Comment: I am sorry but edit that was suggested did the change, I am using exactly what you suggested.

Comment: You need to make the change to the first two lines...  You have to specify the port number after the -p flag.  In your code you have `6443:443` and `7443:443` listed twice.  If you are trying to get two different containers on the same machine to talk to each other, you should consider using links. http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Comment: No I am not trying to link two containers. I am trying to run two different containers with different app version talk on different host port. The container's listen on port 443 only.

Comment: add the `-d` flag to run detached mode in the first two containers.  Ensure that all 3 containers are running with: `docker ps` command.

Comment: I face the same issue. I did run docker ps and the containers are running. Sorry I can't paste the output due to comment character limit. The thing that is weird is that the last container that I ran is accessible on browser while for the other I get webpage not available

Comment: run `docker ps -a` and see if there are any stopped containers taking up the port.

Comment: No there are not as I did run docker ps -a and saw all other containers running and no one was using port 6443 or 7443 other than the one that I ran. I think it is related to docker-proxy but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some of Docker UI applications? Maybe it would be easier to do the same thing via UI instead of CLI.

I use my own UI app to do similar things. You can try it if you want https://github.com/alex-agency/AMHub. This is web app which is running inside Docker container.
For install it you only need invoke this cmd: `docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 8000:8000 -e DOCKER=$(which docker) -v /var/run/docker.sock:/docker.sock alexagency/amhub`.

Comment: Alex, please Disclose that it is your github code, if it is. Seems to be.

Comment: Hi Drew, You're right it is mine. I've edited my answer. Is it correct now? Thank you.

Comment: Great. In the future if there is a summary and even a larger block of code or commands (say in one file), just clue people in to save them time hunting through a repository. If that is the case. Remember, you may decide to delete the repository, and invalidate the answer. Keep as much here as possible.